# search a same string in Shell script variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, grep

I have a shell variable, whitch contains a list
    `$a = Albania Andorra Armenia Austria Azerbaijan Belarus Belgium.`
I get a variable through the html page. It's `$b`.
The goal is that if `$b` not exactly the same for example  'A' or 'Andor', the script write: `fail`, but `$b = Andorra`, the script write: `success`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your requirements. What it your question/problem? Please be advised, this is no free code writing service. You need to show some attempt on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following script:

**SCRIPT:**

```
$ cat test_countries.sh 
#!/bin/bash

a="Albania Andorra Armenia Austria Azerbaijan Belarus Belgium"
b=$1 #read the first argument passed to the script

if [ `echo $a | grep -wc $b` -ge 1 ] #run a grep command that will count the number of word matches then branch depending on the result  
then 
        echo success
        exit 0 #default return code when success
else
        (echo fail >&2) #fail is output on stderr
        exit 1 #another value different than 0 in case of error 
fi
```

**DEMO:**

```
$ ./test_countries.sh Belgium
success

$ ./test_countries.sh B
fail
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk only `\< ... \>`:

```
$ awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '
BEGIN {
    if(a~"\\<"b"\\>")
        print "success"
    else 
        print "fail"
}'
```

Other awks would probably work with this:

```
$ awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '
BEGIN {
    split(a,c)
    for(i in c)
        if(b==c[i]) {
            print "success"
            exit
        } 
    print "fail"
}'
```